# XPages Links: can we compute wether to add parameter or not?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a form where users can create "links" in a side box.  These links can refer to a document Inside the database or to an external site.

For "internal" links, I am adding a parameter so I can track the click from the side box (needed for stats), but I don't want to add that parameter for external URLs.

I tried computing the param in the properties, but the link is still built adding  "/?=" at the end of the URL.  Not a big deal, but I'd rather make it clean and just don't add the param part for external URLs.

I can't use the "loaded" property as this param is computed for each link in a repeat control, and I am using a view column in that computation.

Thanks :D

Comment: post the code you use now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a pager, you can set `repeatControler="true"` on the repeat and then use the `loaded` property.

Otherwise you should be able to compute the link, as I do in [this Data View](https://github.com/paulswithers/Key-Dates/blob/develop/xpages-basic/XPages/ByCustomer.xsp), using "Custom language" - combining literal strings and SSJS.

Comment: Paul, thanks a lot for that.  I was unsure to what that property was actually doing.  BTW, just a small correction (not sure if it's related to the fact that I am using 9.01FP4): the property name is actually "repeatControls".